# dynamic "params" in Liferay spring mvc portlet @RequestMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, parameters, liferay-6, request-mapping, spring-portlet-mvc

This is my jsp portlet action

```
<portlet:actionURL var="saveAsDraftURL">
    <portlet:param name="action" value="abc"></portlet:param>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

also 
  action I can do it dynamic by

```
<portlet:param name="action" value="${abcValue}"></portlet:param>
```

and this is my RequestMapping in my controller class

```
@RequestMapping(params = { "action=abc" })
    public void saveTheForm(
```

**is there way if I can make it dynamic the request mapping params in my controller class.**

Comment: Is there some certain set of values for action param-then u need to try using a reg expr else are u looking to map all actions to this method?

Comment: how to use a reg exp? also for each parm action have one controller class and one request mapping(method)